# First attempt at Rebus

Tags: word, visual, rebus

The answer is one word, 6 letters.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it

> Forest?
>  The four goes to for, the -0500 is for EST, which is -500 off of UTC.

Comment: rot13(Pbeerpg nafjre, ohg abg gur rkcynangvba V jnf ybbxvat sbe sbe gur frpbaq unys)

Comment: Okay, I know the other way too, I'll change accordingly.

Comment: @casey, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: "Run, 4-0500, *Run!!*"